# Dynamic properties specified by user

Tags: android, types

i was wondering if there is a chance to create comparable properties for objects defined by the user itself. 
Following case: In my android app, the user creates a object "car", this object has predefined properties like color, size, doors, engine and so on ... but now, the user wants to add an individual property like "length" ... for that the user gets a plus button under the view to add this property ... now he can type in the wanted property, but what he dont want is to define the type of the input!
The users thinks "hey, its pretty obvious that length is expressed with a number so why i have to choose the type for this?"

I dont want to limit the user if i give them only predefined propertys.

I thought about saving every new parameter as a string, but then the values arent comparable anymore ... "900" is bigger than "1000" in a string comparison and so on. And i want to filter data and do queries later.

I dont disagree at all with the idea to let the user choose which type the field is, but i dont want to ask them too much in an android application.

If this all is not possible, how can i smartly get the information for the type from the user?

How can i handle this problem? Can someone give me a hint or keyword to search for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natural sorting might be the thing you are looking for. It will solve the problem with numbers.

Comment: This is that keyword I was missing. Thank You.